User does not have permissions to enable Traffic Analytics for Vnet Flow Logs via Terraform (Azapi)
I create an azapi code to enable Vnet flow logs since its not available yet (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/25982)
I prepared a TF code:
resource "azapi_resource" "vnet-flow-log" {
  type                      = "Microsoft.Network/networkWatchers/flowLogs@2023-11-01"
  name                      = "flow-log-test"
  parent_id                 = data.azurerm_network_watcher.network_watcher.id
  location                  = data.azurerm_network_watcher.network_watcher.location

  body = jsonencode({

    properties = {   
      targetResourceId = var.vnet_id
      storageId        = var.sa_id
      enabled          = true

      flowAnalyticsConfiguration = {
        networkWatcherFlowAnalyticsConfiguration = {
          enabled                  = true
          workspaceId              = data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law.workspace_id
          workspaceRegion          = data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law.location
          workspaceResourceId      = data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law.id
          trafficAnalyticsInterval = 60
        }
      }

      retentionPolicy = {
        days    = 7
        enabled = true
      }

      format = {
        type    = "JSON"
        version = 2
      }
    }
  })
}

but it failed with error:
│ creating/updating Resource: (ResourceId
│ "/subscriptions/ID/resourceGroups/NetworkWatcherRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkWatchers/NetworkWatcher_westeurope/flowLogs/flow-log-test"
│ / Api Version "2023-11-01"): GET
│ https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/ID/providers/Microsoft.Network/locations/westeurope/operations/ID
│ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
│ RESPONSE 200: 200 OK
│ ERROR CODE: TAUserDoesNotHavePermissions
│ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
│ {
│   "status": "Failed",
│   "error": {
│     "code": "TAUserDoesNotHavePermissions",
│     "message": "User does not have permissions to enable Traffic Analytics. Please refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/traffic-analytics#user-access-requirements to know more.",
│     "details": []
│   }
│ }
│ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
│ 
╵

So according to linked documentation i created a role with scopes:
"permissions": [
            {
                "actions": [
                    "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/read",
                    "Microsoft.Network/connections/read",
                    "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/read",
                    "Microsoft.Network/localnetworkgateways/read",
                    "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/read",
                    "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/read",
                    "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/read",
                    "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/read",
                    "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways/read",
                    "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/read",
                    "Microsoft.Network/expressRouteCircuits/read",
                    "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/read",
                    "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/sharedkeys/action",
                    "Microsoft.Insights/DataCollectionRules/Read",
                    "Microsoft.Insights/DataCollectionRules/Write",
                    "Microsoft.Insights/DataCollectionRules/Delete",
                    "Microsoft.Insights/DataCollectionEndpoints/Read",
                    "Microsoft.Insights/DataCollectionEndpoints/Write",
                    "Microsoft.Insights/DataCollectionEndpoints/Delete",
                    "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/*"
                ],
                "notActions": [],
                "dataActions": [],
                "notDataActions": []
            }
        ]

But in Terraform, it throws the same error.
I asigned new custom role on:

Subscription level where Network Watcher is created
Log Analytics resource group level

And still, it does not work.
But i assume its not perrmission issue, since before i created NSG flow logs:
resource "azurerm_network_watcher_flow_log" "nsg_flow_log" {
  network_watcher_name       = data.azurerm_network_watcher.network_watcher.name
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_network_watcher.network_watcher.resource_group_name
  name                       = "flow-log-nsg"
  network_security_group_id  = var.nsg_id
  storage_account_id         = var.sa_id
  enabled                    = true

  retention_policy {
    enabled = true
    days    = 7
  }

  traffic_analytics {
    enabled               = true
    workspace_id          = data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law.workspace_id
    workspace_region      = var.region
    workspace_resource_id = data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law.id
    interval_in_minutes   = 60
  }
}

And it works like a charm, its enabled and traffic analytics in NSG is also created
Why azapi version of vnet logs does not work, but NSG flow logs from azurerm works?

Please check if you have relevent role assigned for the user or SP as mentioned in MSDoc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/traffic-analytics#prerequisites

which type of authentication youre using? is it with SP or User? @michasaucer

I was able achieve your requirement with the custom role and contributor assigned to my user or SP please check once 
with the roles mentioned  and  @michasaucer I was able to create log https://i.imgur.com/ZTnUaJd.png


User does not have permissions to enable Traffic Analytics for Vnet Flow Logs via Terraform (Azapi)

Yes michasaucer, you're right the issue was might not with role but the provider module you're using in both the cases as both are different.
Every provider module has its own requirements and limitations as where azurerm provider have more privilege in enabling the flow logs for vnet when compared to azapi. When I use custom role alone on SP and try to authentication, I faced the same error as we missed out the particular set of permission that required by azapi provider.
In order to cover come this issue as per the MSDoc I tired assign the contributor role to my SP along with custom role as shown below

and provided the credentials in both azurerm and azapi providers.
configuration:

# Provider configuration
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "xxxx"
  client_id       = "xxxx"
  client_secret   = "xxxx"
  tenant_id       = "xxxx"
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source = "azure/azapi"
    }
  }
}

provider "azapi" {
   
  subscription_id = "xxxx"
  client_id       = "xxxx"
  client_secret   = "xxxx"
  tenant_id       = "xxxx"
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "vksb-rg"
  location = "westeurope"
}
.
// continue with rest of the configuration for vnet, subnet, storageaccount, log analytics workspace and role assignment
.
.
resource "azapi_resource" "vnet_flow_log" {
  type      = "Microsoft.Network/networkWatchers/flowLogs@2023-11-01"
  name      = "flow-log-test"
  parent_id = azurerm_network_watcher.network_watcher.id
  location  = azurerm_network_watcher.network_watcher.location

  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      targetResourceId = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.id
      storageId        = azurerm_storage_account.storage.id
      enabled          = true

      flowAnalyticsConfiguration = {
        networkWatcherFlowAnalyticsConfiguration = {
          enabled                  = true
          workspaceId              = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law.workspace_id
          workspaceRegion          = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law.location
          workspaceResourceId      = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law.id
          trafficAnalyticsInterval = 60
        }
      }

      retentionPolicy = {
        days    = 7
        enabled = true
      }

      format = {
        type    = "JSON"
        version = 2
      }
    }
  })
}

deployment:



Reference:
Microsoft.Network/networkWatchers/flowLogs 2023-11-01 - Bicep, ARM template & Terraform AzAPI reference | Microsoft Learn
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/network_watcher_flow_log
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/5403

As i understand, i have to pass azapi config that will require (in the best case scenario) SP to authorize? Because RN for local development i use my personal user account, and on remote indeed i use Service Principal that spins on devops agent. I assume that we have to aim explicitly to something that have access to that resource?

It not mandatory to use SP every time as we only use this approach in remote cases. In my case I have owner privilege over my subscription so in order to test with the custom role I selected this approach we can also do the same with user as well but make sure you have same roles permissions so that you should overcome the authentication issue related to azapi provider then we can remove credentials from provider info @michasaucer

I had the same issue, you just need to add the Monitor Contributor. Then you will be able to enable the traffica analytics.
